# python sqlite code works but i get some errors

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, split

I wrote some code to learn SQL databases. My code works fine like I want it to. But I get this error and want to learn what is that.

```py
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("items.db")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("Create table if not exists weapons (name TEXT,ilvl TEXT,source TEXT)")

weapons_txt = open("C:\\Users\\kaytu\\Desktop\\Python\\Exercises\\weapons.txt","r")

for i in weapons_txt:
    cursor.execute("Insert into weapons values(?,?,?)",(i.split(";")[0],i.split(";")[1],i.split(";")[2],))
    con.commit()

weapons_txt.close()
con.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\kaytu\Desktop\Python\Exercises\Testing.py", line 9, in <module>
    cursor.execute("Insert into weapons values(?,?,?)",(i.split(";")[0],i.split(";")[1],i.split(";")[2],))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And why do i get the "..." string after every source text? [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlxZv.png)

Answer (score 0):

this means that at least one of the lines in the `txt` file has less than two semicolons, check all the lines of the file again

Comment: when you open the file does each line have at least two semicolons?

Comment: here is my txt file:  https://file.io/dlTK562SoWfB

Comment: the page says "The file you requested has been deleted"  , but it's not a problem, just try it on another file containing few lines and make sure each line has at least two semi colons....for example try this file https://file.io/zEhA8KvvILdS

Comment: its exactly like ur file, still getting the error :(

Comment: make sure the file is in the right place and the working directory of the terminal you are using is the same working directory of the file

Comment: @malcom32 I tried the code on my device and it worked without any problems, just check your working directory...And if you want an advice always give it your attention when working with SQL especially.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).